# Does Mother's/Father's Love apply to all potion effects or just healing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

> If you have [adopted a child](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Adoption) and you sleep in the same house as your child, you will receive the **Mother's Love** or **Father's Love** bonus, which makes [healing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Restore_Health) spells and potions more effective.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping

Does the ability (passive) apply only to healing potions? I'd like to know before I grind skills. I didn't plan on having a family until I noticed the abilities that they can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability applies to healing spells and healing potions only. Potion effects other than healing are unaffected.